# How to scatter plot a two dimensional list

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

How can I scatter plot a list of pairs with each axis of the plot representing one of the value in the pair in python? My list looks like this

`[(62725984, 63548262), (64797631, 64619047), (65069350, 65398449), (58960696, 57416785), (58760119, 58666604), (60470606, 61338129), (60728760, 59001882)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be easy. You can extract the pair into two variables as follows:

```
x,y = zip(*<name_of_your_2d_list>)
```

Also, you can pass the same to `scatter` function as

`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(*zip(*<name_of_your_2d_list>)`.

Try the following. It should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot, pylab

data = [(62725984, 63548262), (64797631, 64619047), (65069350, 65398449), (58960696, 57416785), (58760119, 58666604), (60470606, 61338129), (60728760, 59001882)]

matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(*zip(*data)) 
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

try below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import pylab
list1 = [(62725984, 63548262), (64797631, 64619047), (65069350, 65398449), (58960696, 57416785), (58760119, 58666604), (60470606, 61338129), (60728760, 59001882)]
list1 = list(zip(*list1))
pylab.scatter(list(list1[0]),list(list1[1]))
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_plot(list):
  x = []
  y = []
  for i in list:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])

  plt.scatter(x,y)
  plt.show()
```

And simply use this function as below.

```
scatter_plot(list_of_list)
```